# Prove $(1 - \| u \|^2)(1 - \| v \|^2) \le (1 - | \langle u, v \rangle |)^2$ for $\| u \|, \| v \| \le 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was trying for hours to prove this proposition but now i give up. Please, any suggestion?

[[image]][1

[image]

This is an idea. Maybe i committed a mistake.
I appreciate your help

Comment: Please use [mathjax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Solved [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1423511p8010353) found on [approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/).